# can a csv file sheet name be different from the file name and how in c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a csv file name as "ResultData_020000000_2021-01-01_11-43-13.CSV" but while I open this file I see the sheet name as "ResultData_020000000_2021-01-01" , I need to restrict it to "ResultData_020000000".

I am creating .CSV file using code -

```
using (StreamWriter filePath = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(target, fileName), true, Encoding.UTF8)) 
{

}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of sheet names in a csv file. A csv file is simply a text file that is tabular data with separators, there's no such thing as a sheet in CSV, only after it's imported to Excel does it get a sheets name.